# Passing php session and vriables between iframes

Tags: php, variables, session, iframe

I have a site with multiple iframes. The first is a login frame, which starts a php session once a successful login has completed. The code is below:

```
<?php
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
session_start();
$_SESSION["email"] = $user_info[email];
$_SESSION["password"] = $user_info[password];
echo session_id();
?>
```

After the session has started through the login iframe, I expected the session to still be active and the variables to be available in a different iframe (they have the same parent page). Unfortunately, the second iframe creates an entirely new session once it loads and the variables are lost. Help?

How can I keep the session alive and pass the session variables between iframes?

The code in the second iframe looks like this:

```
<?php
header('P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"');
session_start();
echo session_id();
?>
```

The two frames have different session id's.. that's how I know the session isn't being passed successfully.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the iFrame loading a page on the same (sub)domain?

Comment: When is the iFrame loading?  Is it at the same time?  My guess is that the session cookie isn't set when the iFrame is loaded, so it makes a new session.  What happens if you refresh the page/iFrame?

Comment: The iframes are loading on the same domain. The login iframe has to finish processing the login (and thus starting the session) before the second iframe can possibly load. Again, I ask each iframe to echo the session ID and they produce different values. I tried refreshing, no luck :/

Comment: Have you thought about an alternate approach to doing login without leaving initial page - like say AJAX? Managing this in iframes sounds like a painful way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `?PHPSESSID=session_id()` to the iframes url. PHP will detect it when the configuration (php.ini) is set to default.

Answer (score -1):

Problem found.

Turns out the coding was fine, but there were some nitty-gritty details about how my web host (iPage) handles php sessions. Had to get some help editing the php.ini file. The solution is unfortunately above my level of understanding, but at least others know the solution is out there! Thanks to all who helped & commented.